# is there a relation between the fact that the derivative of x^2 is 2x and that the difference between 1,4,9,16, ... is 3, 5, 7, 9, ...?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is there a relation between the fact that the derivative of x^2 is 2x and that the difference between 1,4,9,16, ... is 3, 5, 7, 9, ...?

And why is the difference always 2?

I think there is a relationship, but I can't get how and why...

Comment: $$(2k)^2 \longrightarrow2*(2k)$$
$$(2k-1)^2 \longrightarrow 2(2k-1)$$

integers translate to even integeres, wish it helps

Comment: Take the differences of $1,8,27,64,125,\ldots$ and you get $7,19,37,61,\ldots$.  Take the differences of that and you get $12,18,24,\dots$. Take the differences of that and you get $6,6,\ldots$.  This is associated with $\frac{d^3}{dx^3} x^3 = 3!$.  So yes, there is a relationship.

Comment: One relation is that $f'(n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{(n+h)^2-n^2}{h}$ and   $(n+1)^2 - n^2 = \frac{(n+h)^2-n^2}{h} = 2n+1$, when $h=1$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a relationship.  Note that
$$(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1.$$

So, the difference between a perfect square, $n^2$, and the next perfect square, $(n+1)^2$, is $2n+1$ which is always an odd number.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The derivative of $x^2$ tells you how fast the function $x^2$ increases. The second derivative of $x^2$ tells you how fast the derivative of $x^2$ increases. The second derivative is 2, meaning that the speed at which the rate of growth of $x^2$ increases is fixed. Therefore, the difference of the difference of consecutive squares is constant.

For your second question, let $d_n = (n+1)^2 - n^2 = 2n+1$. Then

$$
d_{n+1}-d_n = 2(n+1)+1 - (2n+1) = 2n+2+1-2n-1 = 2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

This result does not need calculus to be shown, just knowing how to expand $(a+b)^n$ for $n = 2$:

$(x+1) = x^2+2x+1$

Then subtract off $x^2$ (since that is the preceding square) and you get:

$x^2+2x+1-x^2 = 2x+1$

so each successive difference will increase by two (as it depends on $x$, which is incrementing each time)